# Setting any `listing options` changes `tcolorbox` layout

Tags: listings, tcolorbox, layout

I'm using `tcolorbox` to typeset `listings`. When I try to set the `listing options`, the whole layout of the `tcolorbox` changes. Why is that? How do I avoid that? To be clear, I'd like to keep the first layout (with the very narrow padding) with the second code (that sets some `listing options`).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{lstlistingA}{
 size=minimal,
 listing only
}

\newtcblisting{lstlistingB}{
 size=minimal,
 listing only,
 listing options={ basicstyle=\ttfamily }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlistingA}
  foo
  bar
  baz
\end{lstlistingA}

\begin{lstlistingB}
  foo
  bar
  baz
\end{lstlistingB}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: well you are overwriting the defaults (beside other the fontsize, which is small in the default setting). Use `listing options={style=tcblatex, basicstyle= .... }` to keep most of the defaults.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Oof. And how do I keep those TCB defaults without turning on LaTeX syntax highlighting?

Comment: check the definition of the style (in tcblisting.code.tex, `\lstdefinestyle{tcblatex}`), decide which settings you want to keep and then define your own style.